How to use WebSocket multiple connection
I'm making a simple app that requires Websocket with JavaScript & NodeJS. I'm using the WS NPM package.
The issue is, I want to use two connection in the same project, I have both defined at the top of my file like so:
const ws = new WebSocket("wss://pumpportal.fun/api/data");
const wss = new WebSocket("wss://pumpportal.fun/api/data");

ws.on("open", function open() {
  // Subscribing to token creation events
  let payload = {
    method: "subscribeNewToken",
  };
  ws.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
});

And then, after closing the first WebSocket connect, I need to start the second WebSocket process. I'm doing it like so:
// Closing first connection
ws.on("close", (event) => {
     // Trying to open second connection on first connection closed
     wss.on("open", function open() {
        console.log("WSS Action...");
        // Subscribing to trades on tokens
        let payload = {
            method: "subscribeTokenTrade",
                     keys: [tokenMetadata.mint],
            };

         wss.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
     });

But the second connection isn't opening, any help as to how I can do this?
Trying to use two websocket connection, but it's not working. Any help on how I can do it will be appreciated!

You need to call new Websocket after closing the last WS. In your current solution you open two websockets at the same time.
function secondWebSocket() {
    const secondWs = new WebSocket("wss://pumpportal.fun/api/data");

    secondWs.on("open", function() {
        console.log("WSS Action...");
        // Subscribing to trades on tokens
        let payload = {
            method: "subscribeTokenTrade",
            keys: [tokenMetadata.mint],
        };

        secondWs.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
    })
}

function firstWebSocket() {
    const firstWs = new WebSocket("wss://pumpportal.fun/api/data");

    firstWs.on("open", function open() {
        // Subscribing to token creation events
        let payload = {
            method: "subscribeNewToken",
        };
        firstWs.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
    })
    firstWs.on("close", function() {
        secondWebSocket();
    })
}
firstWebSocket();


This works, thanks so much Snayi
